# What are the 3 different contexts a class can be declared?

Tags: java, class, oop

I am told there are **three different contexts** in which a **class can be declared** in Java.
It has to do with the location within a program, but I can't think of what they are.

Obviously a class can be declared at the top of a page, the only other example I can think of is like a nested class?
I feel I may be going about this the wrong way.

Comment: It can be declared inside a method, too (but I don't think I've ever seen that done in practice).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a package

```
package com.example.mypackage;

public class TheClass {
}
```

In a class

```
package com.example.mypackage;

public class OuterClass {
    class InnerClass {
    }
}
```

Anonymously

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbstractClass myObject = new AbstractClass() {
            // overrides and other fields of the
            // anonymous class goes in this block
        };
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** As @daniu stated in the comment, a class can also be created in a method:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        class MethodClass {
        }
        MethodClass myObject = new MethodClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also define a named class in a method.

Comment: How about `Object x = new Object(){public int imAField; pubic boolean imaAFunction(){ return this.imAField>0}}`? I don't think it counts but thought I'd add it.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually 4 distinct syntactic contexts:

1. In the "compilation-unit" context; i.e. a top-level class declaration.

   ```
     package foo;
     public class Bar{}
   ```
2. As a nested class declaration in a class declaration.

   ```
     package moo;
     public class Cow {
         public class Inner {}
     }
   ```
3. As a nested class declaration in a method declaration.

   ```
     package too;
     public class Far {
         public void test() {
             class MethodInner{}
         }
     }
   ```
4. As an anonymous class declaration in a `new` expression.  The expression could appear in a variety of contexts.  For example:

   ```
     package goo;
     public class Tar {
         public void test() {
             Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                 public run() { }
             };
         }
     }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you are looking for:

```
public class TopLevel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TopLevel topLevel = new TopLevel();
        Nested nested = new TopLevel.Nested();
        Inner inner = topLevel.new Inner();
    }

    public static class Nested {
    }

    public class Inner {
    }
}
```